# Safe, checked cast to C++ base class without using an extra line

Tags: c++, casting

Say I have class `B` inheriting from class `A`, and consider the following code:

```
void f(B& b) {
  A& a = b;
  g(a);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the extra line for the cast?  Note that the following `static_cast` version is not equivalent, since it allows upcasts in addition to downcasts:

```
// Potentially dangerous: doesn't check that B inherits from A
void f(B& b) {
  g(static_cast<A&>(b));
}
```

Edit: I cannot rely on implicit coercion to avoid the cast entirely, as in Brian's answer.  Today the reason is that `g` is templates and I want to avoid unnecessary instantiations, but there are other reasons that have come up for me in the past.  In any case, I do need some kind of explicit cast to get a value of type `A&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `g` has prototype

```
void g(A& a);
```

then no cast is necessary at all; instead

```
g(b)
```

will simply implicitly convert lvalue of `B` to lvalue of `A` as long as `B` is indeed derived from `A`. If `A` is derived from `B`, compilation will fail (unless for some weird reason you added a user-defined conversion from `B` to `A`...)

**Edit**: If you really need the *argument* to have type "lvalue of `A`" and want to avoid casting to derived class then consider [boost::implicit_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/implicit_cast.hpp).

Comment: Unless of course it's non-public inheritance (which it probably is not, else `A& a = b` would have yielded an error).

Comment: Sorry, I left out a detail: I really do want to pass type A to g, not type B.  In the particular motivating example, this avoids unnecessary template instantiations, but there are other reasons.  I will edit the question to add this constraint.

Comment: Thanks, the existence of that pretty much implies there's no native language feature that will do.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Actually, you could use a Lambda ;-)